# How to post Json String and attach file(Multipart) at a time in Android

Tags: android, sdk

How to post Json String and attach file(Multipart) at a time in Android?

I have a form. Where first name,last name, and image attachment option is there. In submit button i want to post the data in server at a time ,first name,last name,and image also.How to do that.Please suggest me. thanks in advance.

Comment: Use Retrofit for making api calls like multipart file upload

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at my this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/45277255/7290822

you can add parameters in this method and post them on the server:

```
@Override
                        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                            Log.e(TAG,"Inside getParams");

                            // Posting parameters to login url
                            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                            params.put("time", yourTime);
                            params.put("firstName", firstName);

                            return params;
                        }
```

Hope it helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

Retrofit is a network library that every developer should use, this is my personal opinion.

It's very easy to use and handle multipart attachment is also. Please find the link as below for the multipart.

https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-passing-multiple-parts-along-a-file-with-partmap